# IOS: Accessing another game's achievements through gamecenter

Tags: ios, game-center, achievements

I have IOS gameA and and IOS gameB. Is it possible for gameA to check Game Center and see if gameB has a specific achievement completed?

Answer (score 2):

No? as the gamecenter checks your game through your apple bundle id..